# curve fitting in python is fitting in my curve

Tags: python, curve-fitting

```
def sigmoid_function(x1,k,xo,a,c):
    return (a/ (1+ np.exp(-k*(x1-xo))))+c

x_data=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35]

y_data =[0.08965066,0.08990541,0.090073960.09013885,0.09021248,0.09038204,
 0.09044601,0.09062396,0.09074469,0.09097924,0.09101625,0.09110833,
 0.09130073,0.09153685,0.09165991,0.09189038,0.09236043,0.09329333,
 0.09470363,0.09750811,0.10305867,0.11295684,0.12767181,0.14647349,
 0.16744916,0.18869261,0.20908784,0.22828775,0.2459888 ,0.262817,
 0.27898482,0.29499955,0.31033699,0.32526762,0.33972489]

result,covariance= optimize.curve_fit(sigmoid_function,x_data,y_data, maxfev=10000)
```

[Curve with exact data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4svE.png)
[Curve fit resut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6ioi.png)

I am new to ml, Please let me know if I can change any parameters in curve_fit().

Comment: First of all correct your **y_data** list , see second and third index

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the optimization at the scale of your observations, then it appears that the optimization function is not working very well.

[image: view of curve fitting]

But if you zoom out and look at the scale of the optimization function, things look quite different.

[image: larger view of curve fitting]

When no bounds or optimization method is provided to `curve_fit` it uses [Levenberg-Marquardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenberg%E2%80%93Marquardt_algorithm#The_solution) which can fail to find the global solution.

> in cases with only one minimum, an uninformed standard guess like β = ( 1 ,
> 1 ,   … ,   1 ) will work fine; in cases with multiple minima, the algorithm converges to the global minimum only if the initial guess is already somewhat close to the final solution.

What you are seeing happen is the optimization function falling into a local minima. Like it says above, you can get around this by providing initial parameters that are closer to the solution so the optimization can avoid that minima trap. For instance by doing this:

```
p0 = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
result, convariance = optimize.curve_fit(sigmoid_function, x_data, y_data, p0)
```

the optimization function behaves as you expect it:

[image]